# Setting up or organizing work in firebase

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase

First time I decided to try `firebase`. But when working with `firebase functions`, I encountered such a problem as `cors`. Ie it turns out I have 3 resources (for now 2) `localhost`, `google cloud` and in the future `prod`. 
Sending requests to `google` (`requesting a function` - primitive `addMessage` - output text), I encounter a `CORS error`. I prescribe `CORS settings` in `firebase functions`, then there is a return from `cors 204` and `httpsCallable` stops at this. Through standard `fetch` - it is normal, there it is possible to change `headers`, and in`httpsCallable` did not find how to change the `headers`. 
In general, a vicious circle is obtained.

Comment: Whats the exact problem? You dont know how to solve cors error?

Comment: I wrote that the CORS had been decided. But the CORS returns to 204. Upon receipt of the inhttpsCallable , the calllabel upon receipt of 204 stops

Comment: Can you know how to change the headers from httpsCallable ?